# RETRIEVE an image as a result of selecting a parent viewmodel and a child viewmodel in ANGULAR JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, mvvm

I created a select menu in Angular and assigned a parent ID for the elements of the first filter list and a child ID for the elements of the second filter list.

By using the

**ng-options="item.name for item in vm.ContextData.selectChildren | filter:{parentId:vm.selectedParent.id}**

I can retrieve the item name for each item in vm. **I'd like to change this function to retrieve an image** so that I can display content in an easy to understand way for end users (My users do need a very graphic explanation of what to do depending on the options they select).

**HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Dependent-Select2 MetroUI and AngularJS</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdn.rawgit.com/olton/Metro-UI-CSS/master/build/css/metro.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdn.rawgit.com/olton/Metro-UI-CSS/master/build/css/metro-responsive.min.css'>



</head>

<body>
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl as vm">
    <div class="flex-grid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell colspan2 margin10">
                <div class="input-control full-size" data-role="select" data-placeholder="Account type" data-allow-clear="true">
                    <select class="full-size" style="display:none" ng-model="vm.selectedParent" ng-options="item.name for item in vm.ContextData.selectParents">
                        <option value=""></option>                        
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell colspan2 margin10">
                <div class="input-control full-size" data-role="select" data-placeholder="Action" data-allow-clear="true">
                    <select class="full-size" style="display:none" ng-model="vm.selectedChild" ng-options="item.name for item in vm.ContextData.selectChildren | filter:{parentId:vm.selectedParent.id}">
                        <option value=""></option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-grid margin10">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="cell colspan3">
                {{vm.selectedParent}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">

            <div class="cell colspan3">
                {{vm.selectedChild}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/olton/Metro-UI-CSS/master/build/js/metro.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js'></script>

    <script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
(function () {
"use strict";
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("AppCtrl", AppCtrl);

function AppCtrl() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.ContextData = {
        selectParents: [{ "id": 1, "name": "NT Account" },
            { "id": 2, "name": "Intranet account" },
            { "id": 3, "name": "Not assigned" },
            { "id": 4, "name": "Not assigned" }],
        selectChildren: 
        /*NT Account*/
        [
            { "id": 1, "parentId": 1, "name": "Create" },
            { "id": 2, "parentId": 1, "name": "Delete" },
            { "id": 3, "parentId": 1, "name": "Modify" },
            { "id": 4, "parentId": 1, "name": "Reset password" },
        /*Intranet account*/
            { "id": 1, "parentId": 2, "name": "Create" },
            { "id": 2, "parentId": 2, "name": "Delete" },
            { "id": 3, "parentId": 2, "name": "Modify" },
            { "id": 4, "parentId": 2, "name": "Reset password" },

        ]
    };            
}
})();
```

Comment: Can you do it with a `ng-change` function on the `<select>` element?

Comment: It did not work :(